# How to pass list of files into Python subprocess

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

I am trying to execute a system executable on UNIX with python. I have used `op.system()` to do this, but really need to use `subprocess.call()` instead. My op.System call is below:

`os.system('gmsh default.msh_timestep%06d* animation_options.geo' %(timestep));`

and works fine. It calls the program gmsh and gmsh reads a series of files specified in `default.msh_timestep%06d*`. I then try to do the equivalent thing with subprocess, but I get errors saying that the files are not there. Below is the subprocesses call:

`call(["gmsh", "default.msh_timestep%06d*" %(timestep), "animation_options.geo"],shell=True);`

Does anyone know what could be going on here? I'm admittedly a Python noob, so this might be a silly question.

Comment: Perhaps [pygmsh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygmsh) can be of use here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globbing is done by the shell for you. In Python, you need to do it yourself. You can use [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to get file list that match the pattern:

```
import glob

call(["gmsh"] + glob.glob("default.msh_timestep%06d*" % (timestep,)) +
     ["animation_options.geo"])
```

If you want to use `shell=True`, pass a string isntead of a list of strings:

```
call("gmsh default.msh_timestep%06d* animation_options.geo" % (timestep,), shell=True)
```

Comment: That works. Thanks so much! My first day programming in python... I've got a lot to learn.